# React Redux: state undefined

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Playing around with react-redux and my state `isCartVisible` is showing undefined, I used simple functional components and I'm storing my stores in different files.

```
//main index.js file
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';    
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import store from './redux-store/store';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(<Provider store={store}><App /></Provider>);
```

and

```
//App.js

import {  useSelector } from "react-redux";
import Layout from "./components/Layout/Layout";
import Cart from "./components/Cart/Cart";

function App() {
    const cartVisible = useSelector((state) => state.isCartVisible);
  
    return (
        <Layout>
            {cartVisible && <Cart />}
        </Layout>
    );
}
```

and a component deep somewhere inside the app, by clicking the button I wanna toggle my `<Cart>` component

```
//CartButton.js
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";

const CartButton = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const cartShowHandler = () => {
        dispatch({ type: "cartToggle" });       
    };

    return (
        <button onClick={cartShowHandler}>
            Click
        </button>
    );
};
```

and that's my store file, where I've created my store with reducer

```
import { createStore } from "redux";

const uiReducer = (state = { isCartVisible: true }, action) => {
    if (action.type === "cartToggle") {
        state.isCartVisible = !state.isCartVisible;
    }
    return state;
};

const uiStore = createStore(uiReducer);

export default uiStore;
```

Comment: Your code for `App.js` and `CartButton.js` don't look like valid javascript.  It also looks like you're including jsx code in `js` files which is going to confuse the compiler.  I'm surprised it runs at all.

Comment: No, actually I write the code like this here for question purposes here only, I write it correctly in my files, just wanted to show devs my prop name and variables... `CartButton.js` is fine. in the returned `JSX`.

Comment: It's extremely difficult to debug your code when it's deliberately changed into something that won't work.

Comment: Alright, I've updated the code above, you can check, and please let me know what did I miss, the button doesn't seems to work, its not toggling the `<Cart />` component, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never mutate the state. Your condition in reducer should look like this and it will work.

```
 if (action.type === "cartToggle") {
    return { ...state, isCartVisible: !state.isCartVisible};
  }
```

As you have only one key in store in your example at the moment. You can do it this way also.

```
return { isCartVisible: !state.isCartVisible};
```

But it's always a good practice to return the whole state in your reducer's conditions.

Remember that redux do shallow comparison. Which means it checks if reference of an object is changed. In your case it wasnt changed.

Once, I wrote something about this topic in a blog post https://dev.to/machy44/shallow-comparison-in-redux-3a6

Answer (score 0):

In Redux, you can only have one store. So it is very likely that your `useSelector` call actually tries to select data from another store than you are expecting it here.

You could validate that by using something like

```js
const fullState = useSelector(state => state)
console.log(fullState)
```

That said, you are also writing a style of Redux here that is outdated by many years - in modern Redux you are not writing switch..case reducers or string action types. Also, `createStore` is deprecated at this point in favor of `configureStore`.

I would highly recommend you [read about modern Redux](https://redux.js.org/introduction/why-rtk-is-redux-today) and then follow the [official Redux tutorial](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts).

Whatever resources you have been following right now might have given you a very skewed view of how to use Redux.

Comment: hey, sorry for late reply, actually I'm using just redux NOT redux toolkit, I've updated the code above, now you can see my exact code, right now my `<Cartbutton />` is toggling `<Cart />` component. please have a look at above updated code and let me know. Thanks.

Comment: You definitely should be using Redux Toolkit. It is the officially recommended approach for writing any new Redux code since 2019. There is *no* good reason to write legacy Redux code in 2022. As written in the other answer, mutating the store in reducers in legacy Redux is forbidden, so that might be part of your problem there. In RTK, that part would actually work. I'm still irritated by that "multiple stores" thing, that will not fly with react-redux in general. Redux always has one store.

Comment: yes, in RTK it would work because of immer which is used under the hood https://github.com/immerjs/immer. As commented above RTK is used nowdays and you should take care to have only one store. If you are going to have more reducers like `uiReducer`, `somethingElseReducer` .etc you should check `combineReducer` method

Comment: Yes, I know all that, but while having lessons on redux, someone said you can achieve the same thing with **just** redux, so I was trying that out, but obviously, it made my reducer function very lengthy and unmanageable, reason redux-toolkit is recommended, thanks.

Comment: @Mohit of course you can do that. But just take my word as a Redux maintainer: there is a reason we want people to use Toolkit. You should not need to write any of that.